# A Lambert W-function with no real solution?

Tags: lambert-w

Recently I have created this question:

$$(x+1)^xe^{x+1}=(2x)^x$$

And the solution

$$(x+1)^xe^{x+1}=(2x)^x$$$$(x+1)e^{1+\frac 1 x}=2x$$$$(1+\frac 1 x)e^{1+\frac 1 x}=2$$$$1+\frac 1 x=W(2)$$
$$x=\frac 1 {W(2)-1}$$

But *Desmos* shows no solution, can anyone explain what is wrong here?

Comment: $W(2)<1$ and powers of negatives are undefined in the reals.

Comment: What about the complex numbers? Is there a solution?

Comment: You need to define the powers of negatives and complex then.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfy says the solution to
$ze^z=2$ is about
$z≈0.85260550201372549135$
so
$x≈-6.7845137617899467654$.

The problem is defining the specified powers.